# Concurrent signal assignment with vector in VHDL

Tags: concurrency, vhdl, hdl, ghdl

I'm trying to compile this code using GHDL and I get the error: '=>' is expected instead of 'not'. I want the code to not have any processes, neither implicit ones.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY decoder IS PORT 
    (c, b, a, g : IN std_logic;
    y : OUT std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0));
END decoder;

ARCHITECTURE beh_decoder OF decoder IS
BEGIN
    y <= "10000000" WHEN (g NOT (a AND b AND c)) ELSE
         "01000000" WHEN ((a AND g) NOT (b AND c)) ELSE
         "00100000" WHEN ((b AND g) NOT (a AND c)) ELSE
         "00010000" WHEN ((a AND b AND g) NOT c) ELSE
         "00001000" WHEN ((c AND g) NOT (a AND b)) ELSE
         "00000100" WHEN ((a AND c AND g) NOT b) ELSE
         "00000010" WHEN ((b AND c AND g) NOT a) ELSE
         "00000001" WHEN ((a AND g) NOT (b AND c)) ELSE
         "00000000";
END ARCHITECTURE beh_decoder;
```

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.6 Concurrent signal assignment statements "A concurrent signal assignment statement represents an equivalent process statement that assigns values to signals." 14.2 Elaboration of a design hierarchy "The elaboration of a design hierarchy creates a collection of processes interconnected by nets; this collection of processes and nets can then be executed to simulate the behavior of the design." You've got a process whether you want one or not.

Comment: 14.7.3.4 Signal update "A net is a collection of drivers, signals (including ports and implicit signals), conversion functions, and resolution functions that, taken together, determine the effective and driving values of every signal on the net."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The when expressions are using the NOT gate as multi-input gate.

```
g NOT (a AND b AND c)
```

If we substitute Q = (a AND b AND c) you have

```
g NOT Q
```

Which is not meaningful? And likely what GHDL is complaining about.

Did you want

```
g OR NOT (a AND b AND c)
```

or

```
g AND NOT (a AND b AND c)
```

Based on your comment, the new code might look like this. You will need to confirm the logic but it should compile.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY decoder IS PORT 
    (c, b, a, g : IN std_logic;
    y : OUT std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0));
END decoder;

ARCHITECTURE beh_decoder OF decoder IS
BEGIN
    y <= "10000000" WHEN (g AND NOT (a AND b AND c)) ELSE
         "01000000" WHEN ((a AND g) AND NOT (b AND c)) ELSE
         "00100000" WHEN ((b AND g) AND NOT (a AND c)) ELSE
         "00010000" WHEN ((a AND b AND g) AND NOT c) ELSE
         "00001000" WHEN ((c AND g) AND NOT (a AND b)) ELSE
         "00000100" WHEN ((a AND c AND g) AND NOT b) ELSE
         "00000010" WHEN ((b AND c AND g) AND NOT a) ELSE
         "00000001" WHEN ((a AND g) AND NOT (b AND c)) ELSE
         "00000000";
END ARCHITECTURE beh_decoder;
```

Comment: g AND NOT (a AND b AND c) is the right thing, just figured that myself too. Then it gave me "no function declarations for operator "and""

Comment: Can you show how you changed the code, this sounds like a new syntax error. I added a version that should compile, but you need to confirm the logic is correct.

Comment: Weird, I get the same error with your code and it seems to be exactly like mine. Is it perhaps something with the std_logic or such?

Comment: I just compiled the code with ghdl and it did not give any errors. Can you share your ghdl command line.

Comment: renshencha@debian ~ % ghdl -a decoder.vhdl
decoder.vhdl:12:29:error: no function declarations for operator "and"
decoder.vhdl:13:37:error: no function declarations for operator "and"
decoder.vhdl:14:37:error: no function declarations for operator "and"
decoder.vhdl:15:43:error: no function declarations for operator "and"
... same up to line 19

Comment: Prior to the 2008 standard you had to be more verbose. For example your first WHEN would have to be `(g = '1' AND NOT (a = '1' AND b = '1' AND c = '1'))` using that you could remove some of the NOT operators.

Comment: Yep, that's it. 93 is the latest standard on Debian due to licensing reasons and when I did roughly the same kind of things some months ago on FreeBSD the 08 standard was included. Now it works, thanks guys!

Comment: 10.5.3 Conditional signal assignments "... represents an equivalent if statement ..." 10.8 If statement "... the condition specified after if, and any conditions specified after elsif, are evaluated in succession ... until one evaluates to TRUE or all conditions are evaluated and yield FALSE. ... " 9.2.9 Condition operator  "In certain circumstances, the condition operator is implicitly applied to an expression that occurs as a condition in any of the following places:"..."— After when in a conditional signal assignment statement"...